# writing search criteria java

Tags: java

I have an arraylist of objects which consist of following fields:

- int userID
- int accountID
- String accountHoldersName
- String accountType
- double Balance
- String accountStatus

Somewhere in my program I have to ask the user to enter search criteria for each field. If the user leaves a field blank, it should not be included in the search. i.e. if the user does not specify an account holder name then all accounts matching other criteria with an account holder name should be displayed.

I don't know how to write an if() for such a comparison where I may not have a value to compare.

```
String acT;
String holdersN;
String acStat;
int usrId = 0, acId = 0;
double bal = 0;

System.out.println("SEARCH MENU:\n");
System.out.print("Account ID : ");
acId = sc.nextInt();
System.out.print("User ID: ");
usrId = sc.nextInt();
System.out.print("Balance: ");
bal = sc.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Holders Name : ");
holdersN = sc.nextLine();
System.out.print("Type (Savings Current): ");
acT = sc.nextLine();
sc.nextLine();
System.out.print("Status: ");
acStat = sc.nextLine();

System.out.println("\n===== SEARCH RESULTS =====\n");
System.out.println("Account ID\tUser ID\tHolders Name\tType\tBalance\tStatus");
// accountsInfo is my ArrayList
for(int j = 0;j < accountsInfo.size(); j++)
{
    AccountInformation ac3 =(AccountInformation)accountsInfo.get(j);
    if( // i dont know how to write search criteria here which will compare only those values that are provided by user)
    {
         System.out.println(ac3.accountID +"\t"+ ac3.userID +"\t"+ ac3.holdersName +"\t"+ ac3.accountType +"\t"+ ac3.balance +"\t"+ ac3.accountStatus);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try an OR condition:**

```
if((acId == -1 || ac3.accountID == acId) && (acStat == null/*Empty string*/ || acStat.equals(ac3.accountStatus)) && (so on)) {
     System.out.println(ac3.accountID +"\t"+ ac3.userID +"\t"+ ac3.holdersName +"\t"+ ac3.accountType +"\t"+ ac3.balance +"\t"+ ac3.accountStatus);
}
```

**Hope this helps!**

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do some null value checking either explicitly via `!= null` or implicitly:

```
   if (ac3.holdersName.equalsIgnoreCase(holdersN)) { 
      ....
   }
```

Read up on [String.equalsIgnoreCase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) for more information on how it works. Since you're using `int` in some cases you need to check if they are sensible values since they cannot be null.